# How to get Spring Security to not bypass a controller login mapping?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

If login.jsp posts to `/login/submit`:

```
<form action="/login/submit" method="post">
```

and the `applicationContext.xml` defines a `form-login` element:

```
<form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login/submit" authentication-failure-url="/login/error" />
```

**How do I do some additional handling in a corresponding controller method:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

*I defined such a method but Spring Security never calls it when the `login.jsp` posts its form.* Instead it calls `loadUserByUsername` and handles the authentication successfully without using this controller method.

Comment: What is your end goal?  There are some hooks available to you in Spring Security for customizing the authentication lifecycle, but how and where you integrate depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also what version of Spring Security are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @stevels and @ericacm.  More info is needed in order to tell you what the best option is for what you are trying to accomplish.

The controller method is never invoked because, as you may know, spring security login form authentication takes place in a filter: the [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html).  When the form is authenticated successfully by this filter, the request is forwarded on to the target url.  (Or to the login error page if the auth fails).

You'll most likely want to start with this filter when looking to modify some of the default auth behavior.  Don't be afraid to step through the code!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with the feature called "target url". Define a forced, default success  target url -- e.g. /login.submit.result. This will redirect after a successful login to that specific url which you can map and control by any controller in the context. Of course, this will disable the origin intent of "target url". If you plan to use this solution and have to redirect to pages after login, well, then you have to build an additional "target url" layer on top of the existing one (based on a variable or internal session param).